# No wifi adapter found on Ubuntu after run Windows

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, iwlwifi, msi

Recently I have bought a MSI Prestige 15 and dual booted it with Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 18.04.3.
Every time I turn off Ubuntu and enter Windows, the next time I enter ubuntu it has no "wifi adapter found". After that if I go to Windows again and disconnect the wifi network, Ubuntu finds wifi again. I got the firmware for the wifi adapter from official Intel Linux support [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) firmware (iwlwifi-cc-46).

Wifi adapter : Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz

Linux Kernel: 5.3.9-050309-generic

Comment: Does this happen on Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: Yes it happens @Pilot6.

Comment: same issue here. Also found a reddit post about this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187743/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-after-run-windows

Answer (score 1):

I disabled fastboot (Fast Startup) in Windows 10 [Image Tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) and now I don't need to disable the Wifi Card before shutdown Windows. My laptop is MSI Prestige 15 A10SC 044XES